# Change price labels in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the price **labels** in **Magento**. How can I achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change label either using language translation file ( `app/locale/language_pack/Mage_Cataloge.csv` )

**(make sure you are changing in right language pack) And clear Cache**

or using template file of your theme folder

**For Old Price** :

> theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml

**For Regular Price** :

> theme/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Comment: Hello, i change it in app/locale/language_pack/Mage_Cataloge.csv, for the field regular price, but nothing happens..

Comment: make sure you are changing in right language pack, I have updated the answer too.

Comment: Hi Naveed i correct the field of 39.90, but i dont' know the filed name of 31.92 ? Could  you please help me one more time

Comment: what label is showing there ? as per your screen there is only one label coming. could you share url with me to check it

Comment: Unfortunately i can not share the url, yes indeed there is no label. it is exactly like the screenshot

Comment: what does this label say ? Special price ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 different ways. First 2 are translation methods and the third one (not recommended) is direct changes in the template files.

**Method 1 (Using theme's specific translation file):** Open app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/locale/[xx_XX]/translate.csv and add your translation in the following format:

> "text to translate", "translated text"

You need to put one string per line.

**Method 2 (Using module's translation file):** As Naveed suggested, you can add your translation in app/locale/[xx_XX]]/Mage_Catalog.csv file in the following format:

> "text to translate", "translated text"

**Note:** Here xx_XX is your locale folder name. For example **`en_US`**

**Method 3 (Direct changes in the template files):** If none of the above works, then you can make direct change your teplate files. For example in your case, you need to make changes in:

**`app/design/[themepackage]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml`**

Please let me know if it helped.